# remove default pagination on woocommerce shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, pagination

how can I remove default pagination on woocommerce shop page ?
and then use my custom pagination (or use pagination plugin) on woocommerce shop page

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer :

1) remove woocommerce pagination in theme functions.php :

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'storefront_woocommerce_pagination', 30 );
```

[storefront woocommerce template hooks](https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/blob/8c510114a14f622e2219178a47c7da6d11556cb7/inc/woocommerce/storefront-woocommerce-template-hooks.php)

2) use the below code for customize your pagination in functions.php :

```
    function bittersweet_pagination() {

global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

$pages = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type'  => 'array',
    ) );
    if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
        echo '<div class="pagination-wrap"><ul class="pagination">';
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                echo "<li>$page</li>";
        }
       echo '</ul></div>';
        }
}
```

Comment: Well this works if you have Storefront...not so much if you're using other themes. Notice that 'storefront_woocommerce_pagination' refers to the WooCommerce Storefront theme. If someone uses this and doesn't put their theme there instead of Storefront it won't work.

Comment: This also did not work for me

Answer (score 4):

Add below code in file `functions.php`:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks . But I wanted to use custom layout.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to locate the right file in the plugins/woocommerce/templates directory and make a woocommerce directory in your theme or child theme and copy it there, and edit it to your liking.

Or you could find the action that puts it there in the first place and remove it with remove_action in your theme-s functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

This page on the WooCommerce website gave a better answer for me than anything answers on this page: https://woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-displayed-per-page/